# Where to set Hibernate FlushMode?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, flush

I have an IntelliJ project using Spring MVC and with Hibernate FlushMode set to auto as default.
The problem is: when I try to delete an object from the db, using the web interface, it works fine, but after the third time I do that, the interface becomes not responsive (even though Hibernate receives the command to delete that certain object with that certain ID) and I have to reboot my WildFly server.

Any idea where I can change that? Is there a way to set it in a configuration file or I have to invoke a method to set it? And even if the problem is the FlushMode itself.
Regards

UPDATE: After testing several things, I think I finally found the root of the problem. If I access the db for more than three times consecutively, the server becomes unresponsive. How can I overcome this?

UPDATE#2: I found that the problem was that in the Dao the connection was opened but never closed (there wasn't a line "session.close()" just to be clear). And that was the reason After three pooling from the db, was it either to add items, delete them or just get infos, the server became unresponsive. Now everything works perfectly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually didn't get your question properly. 
The third time you try to delete something from your frontend, the web page gets stuck? The third time you make a delete request is the request stuck with hibernate? Could be a little clear about what actually is happening/or what issue you are facing.

To answer your question - how to setFlushMode in hibernate:

1. In case you using EntityManager -> entityManager.setFlushMode(FlushModeType.) -> JPA supports AUTO and COMMIT
2. In case you using SessionFactory:

   - sessionFactory.setHibernateFlushMode(FlushMode.) -> **From hibernate 5**
     OR
   - sessionFactory.setFlushMode(FlushMode.) -> **Before Hibernate 5**
     (NOTE: Please check the docs for accurate version of hibernate from which setFlushMode is deprecated.
     Hibernate supports 4 modes of flush -> AUTO/COMMIT/ALWAYS/MANUAL

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't explain myself well. As you said the problem is that the third time I try to delete something from the frontend, the web page gets stuck. I have no errors and no warnings in the terminal, so the fact that it had something to do with Hbernate is only my assumption. Of course it could be something else.

Comment: Restart your server in debugging. And then debug each line where it might cause the issue. I do not think flush has anything to do with this. Hibernate has AUTO flush on, so it does the flush in case it is required. The documentation tells about the conditions, you can read about it - https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/orm/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#flushing-auto.

Maybe it has something to do with your queries. Check your queries too.

Comment: At the top of my head, I can think of - query execution is taking time for that particular resource/data. Maybe there is a connection leak in case you handling sessions and transactions by self and not closing them, so your pool is depleted. You can actually check your live sessions/transactions from the database all well. I

Comment: How can I do it? I mean, checking live sessions/transactions. Thank you so much for the heads-up!

Comment: The ways are different for different DB. I am not an expert on DBA side. I usually google this stuff. But I know db tables hold this data - live sessions and session details. Again in order to see these, your user needs root privileges.If you testing on local db, I think its fine. Plus you need to check the session handling and transaction.

Comment: I think the problem is your connection pool size getting depleted. One solution is to increase the connection pool size but that is not the optimal solution. You need to manage your connection resources. If you using Session to connect to DB, they wrap around a Connection, which is saying -> 1 session, 1 connection to DB and thus 1 connection thread from your pool depleted. In case you not closing them, these remain open causing resource leak and thus next subsequent calls are waiting for a free connection, but cannot. As a result, your next requests are suffering.

Comment: Hibernate Architecture - [link](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#architecture-overview)

Connection pooling: [link](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#database)

Comment: The problem was the fact that the session was opened to connect to the db but never closed. I had a template so I didn't notice this fact, after you gave me those heads-up I checked everything from the beginning and found this. So thank you so much!

Comment: Glad, I could be of help. :)